# Binding custom object list to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a class

```
public class ServerList
{
    public ServerList(string ipAdress, int port)
    {
        IPAdress = ipAdress;
        Port = port;
    }

    public string IPAdress { get; private set; }
    public int Port { get; private set; }
}
```

In a second class called AddServerWindow I have a list with ServerList objects

```
public ObservableCollection<ServerList> ServerLists = new ObservableCollection<ServerList>();
```

How can I bind it to datagrid placed on mainwindow.
I'm trying smth like this:
In MainWindow.cs

```
DataContext = new
        {
            dump = this,
            server = new AddServerWindow(),
        };
```

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Server" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding server.IPAdress}"></DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Port" IsReadOnly="True" Width="0.6*" Binding="{Binding server.Port}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

After changed to code below, DataGrid is still empty but it now have 10 columns

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ServerLists}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the ItemsSource of the DataGrid.  Once you do that, the DataContext for each row is a ServerList, so you can bind the columns directly to IPAdress and Port.  Try something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding server.ServerLists}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding IPAdress}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Port" IsReadOnly="True" Width="0.6*" Binding="{Binding Port}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: As you say, but ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ServerLists}", and now i have 10 empty rows. DataContext changed to this, list moved to MainWindow

Comment: It sounds like the column bindings are still off.  Did you update them to be Binding="{Binding IPAdress}" instead of Binding="{Binding server.IPAdress}"?  Also, if you're having binding problems there are two things that will help diagnose the issues:
1. The output window in visual studio (this will show binding errors)
2. A tool called SnoopWPF https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/.  It can highlight WPF elements with binding errors.
If you code changed (it sounds like it has) make sure you update your original post with the new code.  It sounds like you changed the DataContext?